# Sending notifications with Facebook graph API not authorized with regular users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I have created a Facebook App and published it today with Canvas Web platform.

The users can authorize the application and I can send notifications to them using the Facebook API that appear on their Facebook account on the Web.

However, it works with the developer user but not with regular users. For regular users the API call to send notifications returns this error response:

{"error":{"message":"(#200) Your app is not approved for content update notification at this time", "type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"GPVF+lOxzgp"}}

The application is published and is live. It is for publishing landing pages with videos, when when the user signs up using Facebook, he will get a notification when a new page with a video is published, so he can watch the video inside the Facebook canvas iframe.

What do I need to do to have new content notification approved? I just asked for email and profile permissions and the documentation says it does not need additional permissions to send notifications. So I have not items to submit for review.

I am using this API call described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Comment: That link is  for game notifications. Is your app a game?

Comment: Actually It works for non-game apps as explained in the page linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was doing a mistake which as to pass a type parameter set to the content_update value. Removing that parameter solved the problem.